# Complete Novice using jquery, countdown widget won't work, can someone help?

Tags: jquery, countdown

I am a complete novice at this, never used jquery before, would like to create a countdown widget using divisions and spans for my website but can't seem to get the counter to appear.

The spans will appear and the page is blank. I wonder if my script is wrong or if I need to configure something I have missed?

Here is the page code in question:

```
____________________


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title> Your Title Here </title>
<meta name="Generator" content="Alleycode HTML Editor">
<meta name="Description" content="Your description here...">
<meta name="Keywords" content="Your keywords here...">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/counter.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"> 





</head>

<body>


<div id="cntdwn_wrapper">

<div id="cntdwn_left">

<div id="counter">

<div id="defaultCountdown" class="hasCountdown">

<span class="countdown_row countdown_show4">

<span class="countdown_section"> 
<span class="countdown_amount"> </span>
</span>

<span class="countdown_section"> 
<span class="countdown_amount"> </span>
</span>

<span class="countdown_section"> 
<span class="countdown_amount"> </span>
</span>

<span class="countdown_section"> 
<span class="countdown_amount"> </span>
</span>

</span>

</div>

</div>

</div>

</div>

<div id="cntdwn_right">

<div id="cntdwn_date"><img src="images/events/numbersSmall.png" width="215" height="235"></div>

</div>

<script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>

<script type="text/JavaScript">


  $(function () {
    var counter = new Date();
    counter = new Date(2011, 11-1, 20, 10, 0, 0);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: counter});

    $('#removeCountdown').toggle(function() {
      $(this).text('Re-attach');
      $('#defaultCountdown').countdown('destroy');
    },
    function() {
      $(this).text('Remove');
      $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: counter});
    });
  });


</script>

</body>
</html>

_________________________________
```

My CSS Stylesheet is written thus:

```
/* ----- 11. COUNTDOWN ---------------------------------------*/

#cntdwn_wrapper {
    width: 570px;
    height: 300px;
}

#cntdwn_left {
    float: left;
    width: 355px;
    height: 300px;
}

#chm_countdown_slider {
    width: 355px;
    height: 235px;
}

#counter {
    width: 355px;
    height: 65px;
    background: #333;
    background: url();
}

#cntdwn_right {
    float: left;
    width: 215px;
    height: 300px;
}

#cntdwn_date {
    width: 215px;
    height: 235px;
}

#chm_countdown_button {
    width: 215px;
    height: 65px;
}

a.chm_countdown_button_rollover {
    display: block;
    width: 215px;
    height: 65px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url();
}

a.chm_countdown_button_rollover:hover {
    background-position: 0 -65px;
}

.chm_countdown_button_displace {
    position: absolute;
    left: -5000px;
}

#defaultCountdown {
    float: right;
    width: 240px;
    height: 43px;
    margin: 9px 4px 0 0;
}

.hasCountdown {
    background-color: #333;
}

.countdown_rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}

.countdown_holding span {
    background-color: #333;
}

.countdown_row {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 2px;
    text-align: center;
}

.countdown_show1 .countdown_section {
    width: 98%;
}

.countdown_show2 .countdown_section {
    width: 48%;
}

.countdown_show3 .countdown_section {
    width: 32.5%;
}

.countdown_show4 .countdown_section {
    width: 24.5%;
}

.countdown_show5 .countdown_section {
    width: 19.5%;
}

.countdown_show6 .countdown_section {
    width: 16.25%;
}

.countdown_show7 .countdown_section {
    width: 14%;
}

.countdown_section {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 75%;
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.countdown_amount {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 190%;
}

.countdown_descr {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.nivoSlider {
    position: relative;
}

.nivoSlider img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* If an image is wrapped in a link */

.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 60;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

/* The slices in the Slider */

.nivo-slice {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Caption styles */

.nivo-caption {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 89;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.8; /* Overridden by captionOpacity setting */
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    color: #fdfdfd;
}

.nivo-caption p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}

.nivo-caption a {
    display: inline !important;
}

.nivo-html-caption {
    display: none;
}

/* Direction nav styles (e.g. Next & Prev) */

.nivo-directionNav a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    z-index: 99;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nivo-prevNav {
    left: 0;
}

.nivo-nextNav {
    right: 0;
}

/* Control nav styles (e.g. 1,2,3...) */

.nivo-controlNav a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* -- */

.nivo-controlNav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
}

.nivo-controlNav a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    /*width: 8px;*/
    /*height: 8px;*/
    margin-left: 4px;
    border: 0;
    background: #fdfdfd url(bullets.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    background-position: 0 -8px;
}


.nivo-directionNav a {
    display: block;
    /*width: 30px;*/
    /*height: 34px;*/
    border: 0;
    background: url(arrows.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

a.nivo-nextNav {
    right: 15px;
    background-position: -30px 0;
}

a.nivo-prevNav {
    left: 15px;
}

.nivo-caption {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.nivo-caption a { 
    color: #efe9d1;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

---

It just won't display the counter when I launch it and I am slightly baffled as when I compare to some other source code it should work based on their pages... am I missing something?

All help GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should learn how to use Firebug in Firefox or Chrome's Developer tools (my preference) for debugging issues like this.

Comment: hi, I am working in Chrome and it's not finding any errors, or maybe my knowledge in that area is just too weak to be sure. thanks.

Comment: Errors in *most* JQuery Plugins or objects will not be displayed in a traditional error console. Some developers have utilized Firebugs console.log() and you can return errors in its Console.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have made a fiddle with the plugin and the associated css file.

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/kU55B/

you can look here, there is also a small description on how to install it on your page. 
I am including a reference to the plugin authors jquery.countdown.js and jquery.countdown.css files, and the google hosted jquery api 1.6.2

also remember to change

```
var toDate = new Date(2011, 11-1, 20, 10, 0, 0);
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
    until: toDate
});
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var toDate = new Date(2011, 11-1, 20, 10, 0, 0);
  $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
      until: toDate
  });
});
```

when you are placing it in your page.

after re-evaluating you original post i think it is important to note that you should contain (if possible) all of your script tags in the head of the document. It is not wrong to place them other places, however it is messy and undesired. Also there may be conflicts with when the code is executed.

the line `$(document).ready...` is the line that will ensure all of the HTML elements (or DOM elements) on the page have actually loaded and are ready to use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am not sure where that element of the page is, as in "DOM" - I am not a programmer, I know HTML and CSS but scripting was always a weak point for me and never invested much time in it. So I guess I should be clear and let you know that I really need this to be laid out in layman's terms for me :( Thanks again

Comment: What he means is that you should wrap the existing js that you have with the snippet that he provided.  That will ensure that your script will wait until the page elements are finished loading to execute.  Other wise they may not exist in the page("DOM") thus the scipt will fail

Comment: "DOM" refers to the Document Object Model.. You can read up on it here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model Also, if you plan on using Javascript on your pages you may want to read up on Object Oriented Programming or OOP

Comment: much obliged, will test now. the version of jquery.min.js is 1.3.2

Comment: you'd do yourself a favour by upgrading to the newest 1.6.2 (less bugs, more complete)

Comment: Here is a link to Googles hosted version of the API https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
you can link directly to this from your page if you would prefer, or save it locally and link.

Comment: debugging in the chrome console shows that the stylesheet is interpreted as an image? Maybe that's the issue, need to have a look at the stylesheet so

Comment: need a script that can countdown until Nov 20 2011. one that can fit into spans or divs to be used with a background image - just looking for simple text digits is all.

Comment: my fiddle will show you how to do this.. i personally believe picking up a book on javascript will GREATLY help you out if you plan on doing any web development in the future. Always remember.. JQuery IS Javascript.

Comment: thanks, this is beginning to work now. I will fiddle around. Thanks for your help rlemon.

Comment: no problem. glad to help, and welcome to StackOverflow. remember if you like an answer or find it helpful to upvote it. ones you find not helpful or off topic you can downvote (the arrows to the left of the answer). When you find an answer that works you can accept it by clicking the checkmark beside the answer. Note, you can only accept one answer but you can upvote multiple answers. Happy Coding!